# Function to return a chrono::duration using templates for the time unit

Tags: c++, templates, time, c++-chrono

I'm new to C++ templates and I'm trying to write a function which returns a chrono::duration with the specified time unit and type. For instance, this line gives me the time difference in seconds as double:

```
std::chrono::duration<double> secd =
     std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double,std::ratio<1>>>(end - start);
```

I have a class function which gives me a time duration, and **I would like to use templates to indicate the type and unit for the return value** (in the previous example, that would be double and ratio<1>). What I would like to have is something similar to this pseudocode:

```
template typename<class T, class R> std::chrono::duration<T, R> getStepTime() {
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<T, R>>(_time);
}
```

where `_time` is a class member with the duration. All my attempts so far didn't even compile.

In case there is a better way to achieve this without using templates, I'm all ears.

Comment: If you want genericity on the return type, you need templates!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad usage of `typename` and there's a missing closing `>` in your template. Here is a tweaked example to test compilation :

```
template <typename T, typename R> 
std::chrono::duration<T, R> getStepTime() 
{
    std::chrono::duration<T, R> duration;
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<T, R>>(duration);
}
```

http://ideone.com/QGYm8u

Comment: Both answers work, thank you all! :) I just wanted to say (for future googlers) that since my function was inside a class, I had to put the templated code in the header, otherwise it didn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Bad usage of `typename` keyword; try

```
template<typename T, typename R> 
std::chrono::duration<T, R> getStepTime(Step step) {
   return
     std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<T, R>>(_time);
}
```

but you should show more code. Your example is too small to be even tested.