# How to return a duration type using chrono

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I am writing a class function that returns a duration in microseconds using the chrono library.

```
std::chrono::duration<std::chrono::miroseconds> stop_watch::get_time() {
   auto length = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop_time - start_time);
   return length;
}
```

For some reason my compiler is throwing up at me. All help appreciated thanks!

Comment: Can't you just return std::chrono::microseconds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
std::chrono::microseconds
stop_watch::get_time()
{
   using namespace std::chrono;
   return duration_cast<microseconds>(stop_time - start_time);
}
```

Comment: This does not look like the best possible answer. The real answer would be to return a duration without specialization of the unit. Could you improve the answer?

Comment: That would make this an answer to another question, not the OP's question.

Comment: ups you are right. Google took me to this question when i wanted the generic solution. The generic solution is something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/a/20813563/227990

Comment: I don't like the solution @PauloNeves linked to as it requires the caller to specify the type returned value, in a pretty ugly way. I prefer to use `std::chrono::duration<double>` as it has worked for me in the generic case.

Comment: Returning `std::chrono::duration<double>` is perfectly acceptable if you don't want to return `microseconds` as the OP requested, and if you don't want to do the templated solution.  `std::chrono::duration<double>` means `seconds` with a representation of `double`.  `duration<double>` is neither better nor worse than `microseconds`, or the templated solution.  They are all just different, with each having advantages over the other.  And that is why `<chrono>` allows them all.